# WebGL in react-three-fiber custom shader freezes on props change or window resize

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have a custom shader material in a react-three-fiber scene, which has some animation happening in the shader material itself. I have the uniforms set to update on a dark mode toggle as well using the useUpdate hook. However, whenever I resize the window, or whenever I toggle dark mode, the animation in the shader material freezes and the dark mode does not toggle. The orbit controls on the plane plane buffer geometry still work however, so it is not the scene that is frozen, but just the shader material itself. If I have dark mode toggled and I do a hot reload, the shader material updates and I see the shader material in its dark mode state, but that is the only way I can achieve that. Any time I toggle dark mode from its original state, it just freezes. Even if I open dev tools and the window resizes from that, the shader animation freezes.

I've scoured the internet for anyone who has had this problem, and unless I'm not phrasing it correctly, I can't seem to find anything.

Does anyone know what would be causing this? Everything else seems to be working fine aside from this shader material freezing up on any state change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find the solution here for any future readers: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/discussions/440